# Java spark UDF that returns array of Integers gives me ClassException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

6 and Im trying to write a UDF that takes an Array of strings looking like:

```
String[] lol = {"1,2,3","1,2,3","2,3,4","1,4,5,6,7"};
```

I want the UDF to return an array of integers without duplicates.

I start by collecting list in my query form a DataFrame that has two fields, userid and category which is a string that looks like "1,2,3" and group by user.

`df.groupBy("userid").agg(collect_list("category").as("categories")).write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("path");`

Then I want to run my UDF:

```
ctx.read().parquet("path").select(col("userid"), trimCategories3("categories", ctx).as("categories")).show();
```

My UDF:

```
public static Column trimCategories3(String column, SQLContext ctx) {
  UDF1 udf = new UDF1<String[], Integer[]>() {
    @Override
    public Integer[] call(String[] categories) throws Exception {
      Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
      for(String s : categories) {
        Set<Integer> med = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\,"))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        result.addAll(med);
      }
      return result.toArray(new Integer[result.size()]);
    }
  };
  ctx.udf().register("trimCategories", udf, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType));
  return callUDF("trimCategories", col(column));
}
```

This gives me:
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Since I'm kind of new to programming and don't know Scala I could use some help. In the spark error log the I get the line number where `UDF1 udf = new UDF1<String[], Integer[]>() {` starts. 
The code works when I try running it in a test class. Would appreciate some guidance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, which was that the input type of the UDF was the Scala WrappedArray. The strange part (for me) was that the collect_list function (which in the documenation should return a list) returned a Scala Wrapped array, and when I earlier ran the printSchema function it said type array:string. That was the reason why i set the Input type of the UDF to String[]. Solution in code:

```
public static Column trimCategories3(String column, SQLContext ctx) {
UDF1 udf = new UDF1<WrappedArray<String>, Integer[]>() {
  @Override
  public Integer[] call(WrappedArray<String> categories) throws Exception {
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
    scala.collection.Iterator it = categories.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String s = (String) it.next();
      Set<Integer> med = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\,"))
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
      result.addAll(med);
    }
    return result.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
  }
};
ctx.udf().register("trimCategories", udf, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType));
return callUDF("trimCategories", col(column));
}
```